# Android Login and pasting first and secondnames to user area

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

Hi guys I need your help, I am stuck in that place. I would like to have first and secondname pasted to user area to appear automatically after logging in. The problem is the user area is in different java class than the one which comes next after log in activity.

Here is the part of the code from log in activity

```
    if(session.loggedin()){
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }



    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String email = etemail.getText().toString();
            final String password = etpassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success){

                            String firstusername = jsonResponse.getString("firstusername");
                            String secondusername = jsonResponse.getString("secondusername");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("firstusername", firstusername);
                            intent.putExtra("secondusername", secondusername);

                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                            session.SetLoggedIn(true);
```

And here is the code from the user activity

```
/*
    Code for showing users name and last name
     */

    final TextView firstUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstusername);
    final TextView secondUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondusername);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String firstusername = intent.getStringExtra("firstusername");
    String secondusername = intent.getStringExtra("secondusername");

    firstUsername.setText(firstusername);
    secondUsername.setText(secondusername);
```

Now I uploaded some more code.

Comment: is second code from MainActivity?

Comment: So, what's wrong here?

Comment: Thats the point the ssecond code is form UserActivity class not from MainActivity class

Comment: You want open the `MainActivity`, but access the name and surname in `UserActivity`, right ? If it is true, you can use `sharedPreferences` and pass the name and surname in your MainActivity, then call these in your `UserActivity`

Comment: Yes thats true how can I pass them to UserActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You approach seems correct. First you should check if your extras are not null( for some reason).
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (extras!= null)

Or if the variables you pass(the one you deserialize from json) to intent are not empty

Comment: They aren't, the problem is with that part if(session.loggedin()){
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    } because when I delete that and make some small changes in code the everything is fine with pasting these names but I cannot use shared preferences any more.